# Find columns with non zero values in Hive

Tags: sql, apache, hive

Let's say you have a database with `n` columns, from `col1` to `coln`, where `n` is large.

Would it be possible to find all rows such that at least one column from `colk` to `coln` has a non zero value (assuming columns are  non-negative numbers, and numbers may be missing)?

Comment: what do you mean, "missing". some of the columns contain nulls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Hive's coalesce function (which takes the first non-null value of a series of column inputs) combined with an if statement, something like:

```
select * 
from table
where coalesce(if(col1 > 0, 1, null), if(col2 > 0, 1, null)...) = 1
;
```

The above will return any row where at least one column specified in the coalesce function returned a value of 1. Let me know if this works for you.

Edit: Another method which is a little cleaner (doesn't require you to list all columns) but less flexible:

```
select *
from table tb
where sort_array(array(tb.*))[n-1] > 0
;
```

The above will sort the array ascending so you can check if the largest value in the array is greater than zero and return only those rows.

Comment: If I have many columns, is it possible to tell the function to try all of them without me listing them all?

Comment: I edited my original answer to include a method which wouldn't require you to list all the columns.

Comment: sorry to bug you again. what does [n-1] mean?

Comment: n = the number of columns in your table. The last element of an array of those columns can be accessed by array[n-1] since Hive arrays start at 0.

Answer (score 0):

why so many complicated queries use this;

INSERT INTO DB.1.table_name_1 
SELECT * FROM DB.2_table_name_2
WHERE table_name_1.COL_NAME > 0

INSERT OVERWRITE DB.1.table_name_1 
SELECT * FROM DB.2_table_name_2
WHERE table_name_1.COL_NAME > 0